# What is the recommended approach for encrypting/decrypting large text data in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, security, encryption, aes

I have a client/server application that runs on an intranet, and I have the requirement to encrypt the data in one field of one table of the database. That field is currently TEXT data type, which I have learned is not good for encryption in MySQL. The text stored in the field is similar to an employee performance evaluation containing narrative comments from supervisors. Because of personal information restrictions concerning the network the system runs on, this data cannot be stored in plain text. The data also needs to editable by different users with differ "roles" (authentication levels) via the client side of the application.

So... I have been researching how to encrypt this data, and this is what I understand so far:

- MySQL docs explain the AES functions, and that I should change the field datatype likely to a BLOB to accomodate the encrypted information.
- The key will have to be fixed (i.e. not salted with a user password etc. as I have read on SO), because different users need to be able to edit/review the comments.
- I think the best option is to store the key and pass it as a variable in the php code, similar to what I do with the MySQL login information for the application.

Is using the AES functions in this scenario a suitable way to proceed with this, or are there issues I don't know about? I did wonder about problems (performance?) because of the potential length of the text. Most examples I have found relate to encrypting smaller data: e.g. name, address, credit card numbers, etc.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI, I am going to do a little work with this, and then I will accept an answer. Thanks all for yet another very educational exchange! So much to learn... how long does it take to become an expert at everything? ;)

Comment: @Cavell, be sure to check out http://security.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Johan, or others, any opinion on the approach taken in this post? http://www.itnewb.com/v/PHP-Encryption-Decryption-Using-the-MCrypt-Library-libmcrypt

Comment: it looks solid to me a well written article.

Comment: @Johan Thanks for having a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Security of the DB**

First you need to ask yourself: "why are you encrypting the data in the database?".
The reason is that the database might fall into the wrong hands.
For this reason you cannot store the key in the database itself.
You must assume that all data in the DB is known to an attacker.

Therefore the only answer is to have the key outside the DB.
I would advise to salt the key using data in the same row as the article, so that an attacker cannot use a rainbow table against all articles.

```
pseudocode for select statement:

SELECT AES_DECRYPT(article, CONCAT(salt, '$secret_key')) FROM articles
WHERE id = '123'
```

**PHP security**
Note that listing the AES encryption key in the PHP source code will also be a fail.
It will have to only live in memory on the computer which also needs to be secure.
An option is to read it in from a remote computer (make the transfer encrypted) that is secure (datacenter with guards) or have a senior official key it in upon program startup.

**How to avoid the MySQL ECB hole**
If you need to have it really secure, you will have to do the encryption in php.

See this article to know why MySQL *(which uses ECB mode)* has a problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29

**pseudocode**

```
<?pseudophp
$secretmessage = $_GET['secret_message_from_user'];
$randomprefix = hash('sha512',$timestampinmilliseconds);
$secretmessage = $randomprefix."@@@@".$secretmessage; 
//$password = "really long password entered by a trusted superuser";
$key256 = hash('sha512',$password); //stuff the password into 256 bits.
//You'll have to check that the output is really 256 bits, an tweak it if not.
$iv =  '1234567890123456'; //this is public, because the iv is already in the text.

printf("iv: %s\n",bin2hex($iv));
printf("key256: %s\n",bin2hex($key256)); //debug stuff
printf("message before\n %s\n",$secretmessage);

//We use AES aka RIJNDAEL.
$cipher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');
if (mcrypt_generic_init($cipher, $key256, $iv) != -1)
{
  // PHP pads with NULL bytes if $cleartext is not a multiple of the block size..
  $cipherText = mcrypt_generic($cipher,$cleartext );
  mcrypt_generic_deinit($cipher);
  // Display the result in hex.
  printf("256-bit encrypted result:\n%s\n\n",bin2hex($cipherText));
}
```

Comment: you critisize my for not telling how to save the $secret key, but yet I don't see a solution from you.

Comment: I am new at this so bear with me: If the secret key is stored separately, as I planned, and the salt is in the row of the table, how does the salt add additional security? If the database is taken, but the key is safe, no problem. If the database is taken, and the key is taken, then the bad guy has the pieces to decrypt. Is the idea that the bad guy wouldn't know where the salt is, and that means they can't create the key even if both db and key are taken? Assuming of course that I don't name the salt field "salt_for_encrypt_key" ;)

Comment: rainbow tables are precomputed. So because the attacker does not know your salt, he cannot use a precomputed rainbow table and do it on his own. so using concat(salt, secret_key) is a fail. you need to build a hash of it e.g. md5(concat(salt, secret_key)), btw -1 for that

Comment: @evildead, I just realized that, and edited the answer. I have gotten into a habit of posting a short answer quick and adding to that if need be, it's one of those annoyances of SO, if you're not quick 10 people with the same answer will precide you while you are typing out a carefully crafted answer. The habit is a bad one, but hard to get out of on SO.

Comment: @Carvell, note that you only really need salt to protect against crappy short passwords. if your password is `ACollectionOfDiplomaticMessagesFrom_1966_ToThePresent#` you don't need a salt, because no rainbow table can ever hold that many values to cover 64 char passwords. I would go with this kind of password, rather than `monkey123`

Comment: Johan, I know its hard. I remove your -1 and would appreciate if you can be so kind to remove yours too. This is not a topic you get a perfect solution within a short time, thinking is mandatory her for the right solution. Btw redit so i can remove it

Comment: @Evildead, I upvoted a random other answer you made, I really feel your answer does not reflect best practise on encryption. I'm an IT-auditor BTW, so I know a little about the subject but I'm not an expert, I learn everyday encryption is a really hard subject. I don't care too much about the downvote, you were right about `where to store the key`.

Comment: @johan: ok. But from my point of view, you have to use hybrid encryption to get it really save. There is no chance securing up with only holding symmetric keys in the database. Salted or not doesn't matter, because all Information needed to build the key is in the database.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3299/discussion-between-johan-and-evildead)

Comment: @Johan Just to clarify, in your comment about long passwords, do you actually mean long keys? If so, then I think I understand what you're saying.

Comment: The key length is usually fixed at 128 or 256 bits, so you would actually hash the password _(using SHA2, not broken hashes like MD5 or SHA1)_. And you use the hash as the en/decryption key. Note that the hash and the password as really the same from a security standpoint and either will do to crack the database.

Comment: @Johan I think I am getting confused here with terms. I was referring to key as you called $secret_key above. So I will use MySQL docs terms here to see if I can clarify: suppose my key_str for AES is bubba (no, I wouldn't use that). Are you saying I would do something like (pseudo only): AES_ENCRYPT(article, CONCAT(salt, sha2($secret_key))  ?? Where the secret key is stored on a secure PC and can be accessed as a variable by php?

Comment: @Carvell, yes you can use the pseudo code. But you want to avoid the ECB problem, see wikipedia, you need to do this in php. I'll include php pseudo code in the answer as well.

Comment: @Johan I am going to work my way through it, and yes I think it will be a help. Thanks very much.

Comment: @Johan Final question: when I generate the cipherText, would the recommended database field type to store it still be BLOB?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3305/discussion-between-johan-and-carvell-fenton)

Comment: Accepting this answer because of the extra effort from @Johan in getting me started with the pseudo code and explanations.

Answer (score 6):

Using AES, in CBC or CTR mode is fine.  Avoid ECB mode as it is insecure.  Use PKCS7 padding.

If you want to store the encrypted file as text, rather then a BLOB, then convert the binary cyphertext to Base64 before saving to the database.  Base64 only uses text characters.  You will obviously need to convert the Base64 back to binary before decrypting.

Your major problem is key handling, since everyone with access to the database is going to need the key and you **cannot** store the key in the database itself.  You may want to take some expert advice on this as it is critical.

Comment: +1 For pointing out ECB risk in AES. @Carvell per this answer, you should check if MySQL AES is still using ECB. See this [bug entry](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=15086) in 2005 and it's still there in the source code based on the comments [in the MySQL doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html) as of 2008. This has been a security risk for MySQL AES encryption. To understand why ECB is insecure, see the penguin picture in this [ECB Wikipedia Entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29)

Comment: @rossum Is it any benefit performance wise, etc. to using the field as a BLOB vs the Base64 conversion, or would the conversion hit be small? Also, I don't even know that PKCS7 is, so I guess I have more reading to do :)

Comment: @Carvell, MySQL still uses ECB mode. I suggest doing all en-decryption in php.

Comment: @Carvell, if you do make sure you prefix all messages with a random string, because otherwise because if many blobs have the same layout (and thus the same beginning) an attacker can extract the key by exploiting this fact in a manner very simular to ECB (this was also a major factor in the enigma attacks, many messages had identical beginnings)

Comment: @Johan I'm drowning! I'm drowning! jk :) So if I do the en/decryption all in php, then that means I am not calling the AES functions in MySQL from my query statements in php, but rather using something like Mcrypt in the php code and encrypting the data before it is inserted? Is the concensus that this is more secure?

Comment: @Carvell, Yes, that's the consensus, see the pseudocode in the edited answer.

Comment: +1 for pointing out several security concerns I was unaware of.